# How can I make an AJAX method execute on 2 HTML files?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I have two HTML files and both of them have the same tag, attributes and values as given below. Both of these HTML files are referring to the same AJAX file. And my AJAX code is supposed to change the given textarea tag to a certain message. This works fine but its working only for the HTML file that triggers the AJAX function. I want to execute the below given AJAX method for both the HTML files regardless of which HTML file triggers the AJAX file. How do I do that?

**HTML (2 pages)**

```
<textarea id = "displayMessage" rows = "25" cols = "41" readonly></textarea>
```

**AJAX**

```
$("#displayMessage").val(message);
```

Comment: The *element's* ID is `displayMessage`, but the jquery is looking for the ID `displayChat`.

Comment: is the other page active somewhere (e.g. another tab, another iframe) when you fire the ajax call?

Comment: yes, i have both the html pages active simultaneously on two different tabs.